# Why is merge sort's worst case still n log n?

Tags: mergesort

It was a question on my final I took earlier and I had no idea how to answer it.

Well it was

What is Merge sort's worst case runtime but MORE IMPORTANTLY, why?

Comment: Start with a reversed list and run the algorithm by hand.  Count the number of operations you do.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801861/why-is-merge-sort-worst-case-run-time-o-n-log-n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The divide-and-conquer contributes a log(n) factor.  You divide the array in half log(n) times, and each time you do, for each segment, you have to do a merge on two sorted array.  Merging two sorted arrays is O(n).  The algorithm is just to walk up the two arrays, and walk up the one that's lagging.

Comment: thank you! I said it was going to divide and conquer no matter what.. I don't know how much (if any) points I'll get for it.

Answer (score 0):

The recursion you get is r(n) = O(n) + r(roundup(n/2))+r(rounddown(n/2).
The problem is that you cant use the Masters Theorem for solving this due to the rounding. Hence you can ether do the math or use a little hack-like solution. If ur input isn't a power of two number just "blow it up". Then u can use the masters theorem on r(n) = O(n) + 2r(n/2). Obviously this leads to O(nlogn). The function merge() itself is in O(n), because in the worst case you need n-1 compares.